# Rearranging 4 figures 2*2, and having the top and bottom figures appear on separate pages

Tags: subfloats

I'm having difficulties arranging my 4 figures in a 2*2 and have them appear on different pages.

This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVCYW.jpg

This is the code that I tried (using Overleaf)

```
\begin{figure}[H]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Images/beginner.png}
         \caption{Beginner}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Images/intermediate.png}
         \caption{Intermediate}
     \end{subfigure}
\newline
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Images/advanced.png}
         \caption{Advanced}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Images/expert.png}
         \caption{Experts}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{lorem ipsum}
\end{figure}
```

If i break it up into two pieces and insert

```
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
```

then the problem is fixed but the captions become (a), (b) (a), (b).

I want the first and second figures to appear on the above page because there is a huge blank.

So like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPM2m.jpg

Comment: For two pages, you need two figures.  You can use `\ContinuedFloat` from the caption package to make the caption numbers match up.  And [ht] will almost always look better than [H].

Answer (score 1):

To divide the 2x2 subfigures to fill the blank space left at the bottom of a page (because the 2x2 does not fit but a 2x1 will):

(1) Create two figures using `[ht!]`, with a 1x2 subfigures each.

(2) Add `\clearpage` after the first figure.

(3) Put `\addtocounter{subfigure}{2}` inside the first subfigure of the second page to continue the subfigures numbering.

(4) Decrease the number of the figure's by 1 since the 4 sub-figures are part of the same figure.

The second figure will go to the top of the second page with the right caption.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption} % subfigures <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text for the example

\begin{document}
    
\kant[1-2]
    
 %make two figures
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Beginner}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Intermediate}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}

\clearpage % newpage and clear the floats

\begin{figure*}[ht!]
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}% added <<<<<
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \addtocounter{subfigure}{2}  % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Advanced}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Experts}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{lorem ipsum}
\end{figure*}   
    
\end{document}
```